# Identifying if an IoT Edge layered deployment has completed

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Is there is a reliable way to determine if a given layered deployment has been successfully completed (=~ all edge modules in the deployment are running and configurations are applied) on a given edge device?

I'm wondering about a case where:

1. a new layered deployment is created,
2. the deployment is applied to a device (target condition matches),
3. the edgeAgent marks the deployment as applied and starts downloading the images etc.,
4. while downloading images, the device goes offline.

Is it possible now to determine that the deployment has not been completed on the edge device (other than looking at what modules are reported as running – but this is fragile, and deployments can contain more than just modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom metrics for Automatic Device Management (ADM) deployments might help? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-automatic-device-management#monitor-a-configuration

When you create a layered deployment for IoT Edge, you'll see a couple of pre-cooked custom metrics that you can use as a template.